# first chern class and spin structures

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, complex-geometry, spin-geometry

Let M be a compact complex manifold.  Then is it true that if the first Chern class of M is even, then M admits a spin structure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.  An oriented real vector bundle is spin if and only if its second Stiefel-Whitney class vanishes.  If $E_\mathbb{C}$ is a complex vector bundle and $E_\mathbb{R}$ is the underlying real bundle then the second Stiefel-Whitney class is given by $w_2(E_\mathbb{R}) = c_1(E_\mathbb{C})$ mod 2.  The details appear somewhere in chapter 2 of Spin Geometry by Lawson and Michelsohn.

Comment: More generally, the total Stiefel-Whitney class of $E_{\mathbb R}$ is the reduction mod $2$ of the total Chern class of $E_{\mathbb  C}$. This is Problem 14-B on page 171 of *Characteristic Classes*, by John Milnor and James Stasheff